# google charts in meteor

Tags: meteor, google-visualization, meteorite

I want to add google charts api to my application, I have attched the script tag in header tag like below and then added div tag to my root template like below

```
 <template name="home">
        <head>
            <title>sss</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
          </head> 
        <body>
          <button type="button" id="getData">Get Data</button>
         <div id="chart_div"></div>
        </body> 
    </template>
```

And on button click event i added the chart code as shown in [this page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start?csw=1)

here is the code

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

I'm getting the following error

```
google is not defined
```

**EDIT:** When i add the script tag outside and stating of the html page, it is adding to the dom and when i click on button whole dom is over-writing and nothing is shown up

Any help appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the context of this code, but it sounds like you have a loading issue that I've run across before.  If you set the callback inline with the `google.load` call, it may fix this for you.  Replace these lines:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

with this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: for some random reason if you use two lines google.load will rewrite the content of meteor, at least that happened to me. 1 line made the trick..